# Coverity Scan for JS

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, coverity, coverity-prevent

I have initiated the Coverity scan for the JS using Coverity Wizards.
The capture build step has been completed & failed in to Run analysis step.

The failed message is "**failed with error code 8. See console for details.
Some of your source code may not have been captured, which can result in fewer issues being found.
Please check that all project files in compiled languages are being built by the provided build command, and that all interpreted language files are parsable by the appropriate interpreter.**

Comment: It says "see console for details".  What is the console output?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the console for the build errors you are getting and see if your build is successful. Once your build will be successful ,then only you can run the cov-analysis .
For JavaScript you need to perform buildless capture. Please Run the cov-capture command for the repository/directory that contains your project(s).Kindly refer to cov_analysis_administration_guide.html document .You can find it under /doc/en/ folder.

Furthermore, which version of Coverity you are using ? Use of Coverity Wizard has been deprecated since 2021.09. You can try running the central build or point&scan .